# How to force resolution in VirtualBox headless mode?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, qt

Many will ask why? So, I have some automatic tests implemented using QtTest for my GUI application. I need to trigger them by my CI each time someone commits something. Application needs to be launched in specific resolution (above 1024x600). Of course my build server has no display so I need to launch the test in VBox headless mode. Now the problem is that the dummy display emulated by VBox in headless mode has only 800x600 resolution. I am not able to change it by any switch. My current setup:

```
    VBoxManage convertfromraw --format vdi ${INPUT} ${OUTPUT}
    VBoxManage createvm --name MyTestOS1 --ostype Linux26_64 --register --basefolder ${OUTPUT_DIR}
    VBoxManage modifyvm MyTestOS1 --firmware efi
    VBoxManage modifyvm MyTestOS1 --ioapic on
    VBoxManage modifyvm MyTestOS1 --memory 4096 --vram 256
    VBoxManage modifyvm MyTestOS1 --nic1 nat
    VBoxManage modifyvm MyTestOS1 --uart1 0x3F8 4
    VBoxManage modifyvm MyTestOS1 --uartmode1 tcpserver 8888
    VBoxManage modifyvm MyTestOS1 --graphicscontroller vmsvga --accelerate3d on
    VBoxManage modifyvm MyTestOS1 --monitorcount 1
    VBoxManage setextradata MyTestOS1 CustomVideoMode1 "1024x600x32"
    VBoxManage setextradata MyTestOS1 CustomVideoMode2 "1920x1080x32"
    VBoxManage setextradata MyTestOS1 CustomVideoMode3 "1280x1080x32"
    VBoxManage setextradata MyTestOS1 VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution 1024x600
    VBoxManage setextradata MyTestOS1 GUI/MaxGuestResolution any
    VBoxManage controlvm MyTestOS1 setvideomodehint 1024 600 24
    VBoxManage storagectl MyTestOS1 --name "SATA Controller" --add sata --controller IntelAhci       
    VBoxManage storageattach MyTestOS1 --storagectl "SATA Controller" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium ${OUTPUT}
    VBoxManage export MyTestOS1 --output ${OUTPUT_DIR}/MyTestOS1.ova
```

Did I miss something? Or maybe there is another way to do what I want to do?

Comment: So you’re using Linux and the application is running under Xorg X11, yes? If that’s the case, did you experiment with partial Xorg configs yet and/or `xrandr`?

Comment: @DanielB I use weston + wayland. No Xserver inside. I already have /etc/weston.ini configuration:

`[core]
backend=fbdev-backend.so
shell=kiosk-shell.so

[output]
name=Virtual-1
mode=1024x600
app-ids=xyz.mytestos2

[output]
name=HDMI-A-2
mode=1920x1080
app-ids=xyz.mytestos1`

Comment: If VirtualBox Guest Additions are installed, you may change the guest screen resolution by `VBoxManage controlvm setvideomodehint`.